# Auth.currentUser Info() not showing user attributes react Native Aws App

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native

I am using Auth.currentUser Info() for showing user profile data. Aws amplify is working fine for signup,login part.

It is showing the user name only no other attributes.Not throwing any errors too.

Am I missing any codes here or attributes.

Here is my code example

```
     export default class Tab4Main extends Component {

     state = {
     info: {}
      }

     async componentDidMount() {
     const info = await Auth.currentUserInfo()
     console.log('Returned info: ', info)
     this.setState({ info })
      }



     signOut() {

      Auth.signOut()
     .then(user => {

       console.log('successful sign out!')

               })
       .catch(err => Alert.alert('error signing out: ', err))
          }


          render() {
        const { info } = this.state
        const {username, gender,birthdate } = info



              return (


            <Container>
                <Content>

               <Text style={{paddingTop:50,color:"red"}}>Welcome, 
               {username}
               {gender},
                 {birthdate}
                    </Text>


                <Button rounded block style={{ 
            backgroundColor:"#6e1e11",marginTop:40}} onPress= 
               {this.signOut.bind(this)} >
               <Text style={{fontSize: 18,fontWeight: "bold",color: 
              "#ffffff"}}>Sign Out</Text>
                  </Button>
```

I am adding signup code too .This is working just fine and saving data to the user pools too.And the login is working fine too after confirmation.

```
      state = {
  username:'',
  name: '',
  password: '',
  gender:'',
  birthdate:'',
  confirmationCode: '',

 }
onChangeText(key, value) {
  this.setState({
  [key]: value
  })
  }
   signUp() {
     Auth.signUp({
       username: this.state.username,
       password: this.state.password,
       attributes: {

       gender:this.state.gender,
      birthdate:this.state.birthdate,
      name:this.state.name
     }
    })
    .then(() => this.ShowModalFunction(true) )

     //console.log('successful sign up!'))

     .catch(err => Alert.alert('error signing up!: ', err))
    }
```

Comment: Is there any error shows on the log?

Comment: No Error on console log .App is returning fine on the simulator just no details except username..

Answer (score 1):

Check if your cognito profile has attributes.
You must initially signup with attributes in order to get attribute object in
`Auth.currentUserInfo()` method.

**Signup Code Sample**

```
Auth.signUp({
  username: 'value'
  password: 'value',
  attributes: {
    attr1: 'value1',
    attr2: 'value2',
  },
 }).then((response) => {
   ....
}
```

Then you check if the attributes are there by destructuring using default value.

**Session Code Sample**

```
Auth.currentUserInfo().then((userInfo) => {
  const { attributes = {} } = userInfo;
  console.log(attributes['attr1']);
})
```

Post your Signup code and we will see if you can't solve your issue using this solution.

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer, just added sign up code.

Comment: Could you upvote and verify answer other might find useful.